# Cannot change overlayNoRowsTemplate after grid loaded

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

There are two different situations where there are no rows to display. And I want to change the template each time depending on the situation.
I am updating the `overlayNoRowsTemplate` but the template cannot replaced after the grid has been loaded.
Refreshing the grid doesn't refresh the `overlayNoRowsTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it dynamically only via own `Overlay Component`, cuz `overlayNoRowsTemplate` same as other `gridOptions` doesn't support dynamic changes.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { INoRowsOverlayAngularComp } from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-no-rows-overlay',
    template: `<div class="ag-overlay-loading-center" style="background-color: lightcoral; height: 9%">` +
          `   <i class="fa fa-frown-o"> {{this.params.noRowsMessageFunc()}} </i>` +
          `</div>`
})
export class CustomNoRowsOverlay implements INoRowsOverlayAngularComp {
    private params: any;

    agInit(params): void {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's not hard to set up and also, you will be able to access all related things via `params.api` and `gridOptions.noRowsOverlayComponentParams`.

[Check docs for more info.](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/)

Comment: It is set overlay on grid init, how to change text after grid load ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Grid API's private methods to do this as follows,

```
onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
}
```

In your private method

```
(this.gridApi as any).gridOptionsWrapper.setProperty('overlayNoRowsTemplate', 'newTemplate');
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me in the case where I am catching a response error and want to use the template to say 'Error retrieving data'. I printed this.gridApi's value after the setProperty() call, and it is modified, but the grid does not refresh with the updated template value (and continues to have the initial template shown).